# Vim Keyword Completion

Tags: c, vim

How do I tell the Vim editor about my include files path so that it can auto complete the function names when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>?

For example, I have a C program like below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    sca // here I press control+N, it does not complete to scanf
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your `.vimrc`, add the paths to your `.vimrc`:

```
set path+=/usr/include/**
set path+=/my_include_dir/include
set path+=/my_include_dir/srclib/apr/**
set path+=/my_other_include_dir/srclib/apr-util/**

** means all sub-directories.
*  means all contained directories
.  means all files in the directory of the found file
+= means prepend to existing path (iirc)
```

You can check the paths as well by opening your file and then entering

```
:checkpath
```

This will give you a list of all included files that are missing. N.B. It doesn't seem to handle preprocessor directives, so you will get some false positives. Entering

```
:checkpath!
```

Will give a complete list of found and missing include files.

Answer (score 16):

Also, Important to note there are many completion functions.

```
^x ^o  = "omnicomplete" 
^x ^i  = "included-files completion" 
^x ^f  = "path completion" 
^x ^l  = "Complete this line using one that looks the same"
```

see

```
:help ins-completion
```

for more.

Answer (score 3):

Vim might also know the path already, if the files are in a standard location. 
<C-n> uses the 'complete' option and the flag `i` scans included files. To add `i` to 'complete':

`set complete+=i`

you can also get a tags file from the symbols you want completed, which you can use with:

`set complete+=t`